# Couldn't load FFI package in pharo 3.0 MacOS

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I am using monticello's location as "http://source.squeak.org/FFI" and then trying to load FFI package for MacOS. I could load FFI-Pools,FFI-Kernel. But was unable to load FFI-MacOS, It throws error on "getenv" method. Synatx error:'>'expected. I think I am doing something wrong. Could someone direct me to appropriate link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pharo 3, use the configuration from Configuration Browser:
*World Menu > Tools > Configuration Browser*, then *Install Stable Version*.
All tests are green on OSX 10.9.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you can execute this in your workspace:

```
Gofer it 
    smalltalkhubUser: 'Pharo' project: 'MetaRepoForPharo30';
    configurationOf: 'FFI';
    loadStable
```

Comment: This seems to have disappeared get `Could not access http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/Pharo/MetaRepoForPharo3/main/: ZnHttpUnsuccessful: 404 Not Found`

Comment: No, you hit a smalltalkhub slowdown, but it is there. Just retry :)

Comment: Ah typo in URL add the 0